# Math expression in dynamically created sliders

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to include some mathematical expressions into sliders' labels. It works fine when slider is static. However, it doesn't work when sliders are created via `renderUI`.

Code below works well untill the number of sliders to be created is changed. In such a moment, math mode stops working in all dynamically created sliders. However, math mode still works for static slider and also for other mathematical text.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sliders..."),
  withMathJax(),
  mainPanel(
    # Static slider
    sliderInput(inputId = "slider_alpha",
                label = "\\(\\alpha\\) slider",
                min = 0,
                max = 50,
                value = 30),
    # Text with math mode
    uiOutput("text"),
    # Number of sliders
    numericInput(inputId = "number_of_sliders",
                 label = "Number of sliders",
                 min = 1,
                 max = 3,
                 value = 1,
                 step = 1),
    # Dynamically created sliders
    uiOutput("slider")
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderUI({
    HTML("\\(\\alpha + \\beta = \\gamma\\)")
  })

  output$slider <- renderUI({
    num <- input$number_of_sliders
    sliders <- tagList(
      tags$div(style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;",
               sliderInput("slider_beta", "\\(\\beta\\) slider",
                           value = 5, min = 0, max = 50, step = 1)),
      tags$div(style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;",
               sliderInput("slider_gamma", "\\(\\gamma\\) slider",
                           value = 10, min = 0, max = 50, step = 1)),
      tags$div(style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;",
               sliderInput("slider_gamma", "\\(\\delta\\) slider",
                           value = 10, min = 0, max = 50, step = 1))
    )
    sliders[1:num]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of `withMathJax()`, you should call this function each time, and not only at the beginning, cause of the use of `uiOutput()`.

> This function adds MathJax to the page and typeset the math
>   expressions (if found) in the content .... It only needs to be called
>   once in an app unless the content is rendered after the page is
>   loaded, **e.g. via renderUI, in which case we have to call it explicitly
>   every time** we write math expressions to the output.

If you add `withMathJax` in your first `sliderInput()` in your server part, it seems to work.

```
tags$div(style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;",
         sliderInput("slider_beta", withMathJax("\\(\\beta\\) slider"),
                     value = 5, min = 0, max = 50, step = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: You can also repeat it only once: `sliders <- tagList(withMathJax(), ...`